# Problem with cloning files from git in windows

Tags: windows

I used git in Linux but right now I have to use Windows OS. The problem is that I can not clone files.

I generate a ssh key by using the `ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096` command and copied the key (the long text and added the text in the ssh key file to my git `SSH-key` in setting.

Then try the command :

```
git clone Clone with SSH
```

I exits with this error:

```
git@gitlab.liu.se: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Generally this is a permissions issue. Check permissions on gitlab.liu.se.